# Pandas Percent Change with Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['type', 'value', 'weight']
fizz_or_bang = ['fizz', 'bang', 'fizz', 'bang', 'bang', 'fizz', 'bang', 'bang', 'fizz', 'bang', 'bang', 'fizz', 'bang', 'bang', 'fizz', 'bang']
values = [5, 4, 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 12, 8, 12, 13, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6]
weight = [1, 1, 1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1, 1]

data = {'type': fizz_or_bang, 'value': values, 'weight': weight}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

That looks like:

```
    type    value   weight
0   fizz    5   1.0
1   bang    4   1.0
2   fizz    5   1.0
3   bang    7   0.5
4   bang    9   0.5
5   fizz    4   1.0
6   bang    6   0.5
7   bang    12  0.5
8   fizz    8   1.0
9   bang    12  0.5
10  bang    13  0.5
11  fizz    2   1.0
12  bang    3   0.5
13  bang    4   0.5
14  fizz    8   1.0
15  bang    6   1.0
```

I would like to take the percent change of each `fizz bang` pair, and the average percent change of each `fizz bang bang` trio. I'm a little stumped on how to do this with pandas functions where I would have a forth column holding the percent changes. I know that I can find the percent change of each given row using the `df['my_column'].pct_change()` function, but I'm not sure how to do it with the previously mentioned condition.

Is this possible without dropping the dataframe structure and using a for loop?

Below is the expected output:

```
    type    value   weight  pct_change
0   fizz    5   1.0 NaN
1   bang    4   1.0 -0.200
2   fizz    5   1.0 NaN
3   bang    7   0.5 NaN
4   bang    9   0.5 0.6
5   fizz    4   1.0 NaN
6   bang    6   0.5 NaN
7   bang    12  0.5 1.25
8   fizz    8   1.0 NaN
9   bang    12  0.5 NaN
10  bang    13  0.5 0.5625
11  fizz    2   1.0 NaN
12  bang    3   0.5 NaN
13  bang    4   0.5 0.75
14  fizz    8   1.0 NaN
15  bang    6   1.0 -0.25
```

Fizz bang pair calculation
(bang - fizz) / fizz

Fizz bang bang trio calculation
(((bang1 + bang2) / 2) - fizz) / fizz

Comment: what is you expected output ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited my question to include the expected output.

Comment: How you get 3.5 for row 7 ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't taking the weighted average correctly. It is updated now.

Comment: Please just show the calculation

Comment: I did as a comment in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is need `cumsum`  create the key  , and you need the `first` and `last` value only , so we can not using `pct_change`

```
s=df.type.eq('fizz').cumsum() #Create the subgroup
s1=df.value.mul(df.weight)[df.type.ne('fizz')].groupby(s).sum().values
#using the group key , find the the value we need compare with type == fizz for each group 
s2=df.loc[df.type.eq('fizz'),'value']
#store the value 
df.loc[~s.duplicated(keep='last'),'New']=((s1-s2)/s2).values
# since you only want to assign the value to last line of each group, here we using duplicated 
df
    type  value  weight     New
0   fizz      5     1.0     NaN
1   bang      4     1.0 -0.2000
2   fizz      5     1.0     NaN
3   bang      7     0.5     NaN
4   bang      9     0.5  0.6000
5   fizz      4     1.0     NaN
6   bang      6     0.5     NaN
7   bang     12     0.5  1.2500
8   fizz      8     1.0     NaN
9   bang     12     0.5     NaN
10  bang     13     0.5  0.5625
11  fizz      2     1.0     NaN
12  bang      3     0.5     NaN
13  bang      4     0.5  0.7500
14  fizz      8     1.0     NaN
15  bang      6     1.0 -0.2500
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but these figures are incorrect. If I'm not mistaken, percent change = (the new value - the old value) / the old value. And the weighted percent change in this case = (((new1 + new2) / 2) - old value) / old value

Comment: This works really well, thank you. Do you mind explaining what's going on?